# default application path use in nlog.config file in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

Can any one tell how to pass the application default path to the nlog.config file under the tag of

```xml
<target xsi:type="file" name="error" fileName="E://..//customeExceptionErrorLog.log"
        layout=" ${exception}"/>
```

the filename is here hard code but i want to the path with out hard code and use the default application rootpath.

Answer (score 0):

Use [${basedir}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers) nlog variable

> ${basedir} - The current application domain's base directory.

Something like this should work for you:

```xml
<target xsi:type="file" name="error" 
        fileName="${basedir}/customeExceptionErrorLog.log"
        layout=" ${exception}"/>
```